# Survey on infinite alphabet automata?

Tags: reference-request, fl.formal-languages, automata-theory, survey

The paper "Symbolic Finite State Transducers, Algorithms and Applications" by Bjorner et al (to appear at POPL 2012) describes one type of finite-state, infinite-alphabet automata/transducers by using predicates from any decidable theory as the alphabet. The paper also references quite a few others including:

- "Automata and logics for words and trees over an infinite alphabet" by Segoufin,
- "Finite memory automata" by Kaminski and Francez, FOCS 1990

I'm wondering whether there's a good survey on different infinite alphabet automata models.

Comment: I recently read Bojanczyk et al. "Automata with Group Actions," and it cites Segoufin as *the* survey of this area.

Comment: More recently Bojańczyk also wrote the book "Slightly infinite sets" https://www.mimuw.edu.pl/~bojan/upload/main-10.pdf though I believe it doesn't attempt to be exhaustive.